# Eigenvalues 0 and 1 for non idempotent matrices

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm asked to find a matrix $A$ which only has possible eigenvalues of $0$ and $1$ and is not idempotent.

If $\lambda$ of $A$ is either $0$ or $1$ and $q(\lambda) = 0$ then $q(A) = 0$ with $q(\lambda)$ being a polynomial.

The only polynomial that comes to mind is one such as $q(\lambda) = \lambda^{3} - \lambda$. In this case if $q(\lambda) = 0$ then $\lambda = 1 \lor \lambda = 0$ but this doesn't fit the criteria because the matrices that correspond to this polynomial are either $I_{n}$ or $0_{n}$ which are idempotent.

Comment: $\lambda^3-\lambda = \lambda(\lambda^2-1) = \lambda(\lambda-1)(\lambda+1)$. So $\lambda=-1$ is also a root. Your claim that $q(\lambda)=0$ implies $\lambda=0$ or $\lambda=1$ is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

What is
$\ \ \pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}^n\ ?
$

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}1 & n\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Right.  Can you see how this helps you find the matrix you're looking for, or do you need further hints?

Comment: I need further hints

Comment: You're looking for a matrix $\ A\ $ whose only eigenvalues are $\ 1\ $ or $\ 0\ $ but is not idempotent. What are the eigenvalues of $\ \pmatrix{1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0}\ $? Is it idempotent?